# Check if x second passed, if not wait until x second

Tags: c#, .net

Im struggling a problem.This is for a trading bot, In an exchange, there is a rule. You can not trade after a trade, If you want to trade, you have to wait 5 seconds after first trade. After 5 seconds, trade is up to you, buy,sell or do nothing.

I have stopwatch and I call `aFunction`, after end of the function, timer will start and I call `bFunction` ,if timer value < 5 seconds, It should wait until 5 seconds pass.

I make a `while(true)` and I can check `if(timer>5)` but it will eat cpu and if its single core it will be endless loop during 5 seconds.

Is there any c# way for this ? or any idea ? Sorry for my english and any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

It shouldnt wait 5 seconds, if there is no trade before(5 seconds or more). So thread sleep or Timer doesnt work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0

Comment: @NeilW but with timer , you have to wait always 5 second. Maybe I didnt trade before , and it should enter that function at same time without waiting.

Comment: Various ways to do it, but you could have boolean flag (TradeDisabled) that is changed by a 5 second timer.  If you try to enter a trade while TradeDisable then it's not accepted.  If you want that trade to be accepted but not executed until 5 seconds have passed then you can keep a timestamp of last trade and start a time for 5 seconds MINUS the difference between Now and the timestamp of last trade.

Comment: @mnnavc you can change timer's wait time.

Comment: Be aware of the precision of the timer.  It will not fire at the precise time you want it to, regardless of which timer you're using.  It's a big enough of a difference that if you're racing other automated trading systems they will get there faster.  If you don't care about hitting top of book as quick as possible then a timer makes perfect sense here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a timer based solution.  The important things to note are

- There are several timer classes in .NET.  Choose what's best for
  you.
- It's very important to understand on what `Thread` a timer fires.
- The timer will not fire at *exactly* the interval you set

  ```
   public class Trade
   {
       public string Symbol { get; }
       public DateTime TradeTimeUTC { get; }
   }

   public class Order
   {
       public string Symbol { get; }
   }

   public void SendOrder(Order order)
   {
       //Find most recent trade for this order, out of scope here
       var trade = GetMostRecentTrade(order);
       var differenceInTime = DateTime.UtcNow - trade.TradeTimeUTC;
       if (differenceInTime.TotalSeconds >= 5)
       {
           ActuallySendOrder(order);
           return;
       }
       System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer()
       {
           AutoReset = false,
           Interval = differenceInTime.TotalMilliseconds
       };
       //You're on a ThreadPool thread when this fires, adjust accordingly
       timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => { ActuallySendOrder(order); };
       timer.Start();
   }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this ...

```
bool TradeEnabled = true;
DateTime LastTrade;

Timer TradeEnabler;
Timer TradeExectuer;

void RequestTrade()
{
    if (TradeEnabled)
    {
        ExecuteTrade();
    }
    else
    {    
        TimeSpan delaySpan = DateTime.Now - LastTrade;        
        int delay = (int)delaySpan.TotalMilliseconds;
        TradeExecuter = new Timer(delay);
        TradeExecuter.Elapsed += ExecuteTrade;
        TradeExecuter.Enabled = true;
    }
}

void EnableTrade(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args) 
{
    TradeEnabled = true;
    TradeEnabler.Stop();
    TradeEnabler.Dispose();

}

void ExecuteTrade(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
    // Execute Trade
    TradeExecuter.Stop();
    TradeExecuter.Dispose();
    LastTrade = DateTime.Now;

    TradeEnabled = false;

    TradeEnabler = new Timer(5000);
    TradeEnabler.Elapsed += EnableTrade;
    TradeEnabler.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Hey, Im getting an error like this. **No overload for 'ExecuteTrade' matches delegate 'ElapsedEventHandler'** I checked on google and stackoverflow but your code looks good. How can I fix it ?

Comment: My answer was not complete, for brevity.  It was more to show the architecture of the solution.  The method for handling the timer needs arguments (object source, ElapsedEventArgs e).  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0.  Updating the answer.

Comment: This has threading issues with `TradeEnabled`.

Comment: Yup, use ZerO's answer.